# Join with column having the max sequence number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a margin table

```
  item  margin
0    a       3
1    b       4
2    c       5
```

and an item table

```
  item  sequence
0    a         1
1    a         2
2    a         3
3    b         1
4    b         2
5    c         1
6    c         2
7    c         3
```

I want to join the two table so that the margin will only be joined to the product with maximum sequence number, the desired outcome is

```
  item  sequence  margin
0    a         1     NaN
1    a         2     NaN
2    a         3     3.0
3    b         1     NaN
4    b         2     4.0
5    c         1     NaN
6    c         2     NaN
7    c         3     5.0
```

How to achieve this?

Below is the code for margin and item table

```
import pandas as pd
df_margin=pd.DataFrame({"item":["a","b","c"],"margin":[3,4,5]})
df_item=pd.DataFrame({"item":["a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c"],"sequence":[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) then replace extra values with NaN via [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas-series-where):

```
new_df = df_item.merge(df_margin)
new_df['margin'] = new_df['margin'].where(
    new_df.groupby('item')['sequence'].transform('max').eq(new_df['sequence'])
)
```

Or with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
new_df = df_item.merge(df_margin)
new_df.loc[new_df.groupby('item')['sequence']
               .transform('max').ne(new_df['sequence']), 'margin'] = np.NAN
```

---

Another option would be to [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign) a temp column to both frames df_item with `True` where the value is maximal, and `df_margin` is `True` everywhere then `merge` outer and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop) the temp column:

```
new_df = (
    df_item.assign(
        t=df_item
            .groupby('item')['sequence']
            .transform('max')
            .eq(df_item['sequence'])
    ).merge(df_margin.assign(t=True), how='outer').drop('t', 1)
)
```

Both produce `new_df`:

```
  item  sequence  margin
0    a         1     NaN
1    a         2     NaN
2    a         3     3.0
3    b         1     NaN
4    b         2     4.0
5    c         1     NaN
6    c         2     NaN
7    c         3     5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df_item.merge(df_item.groupby('item')['sequence'].max().\
              reset_index().merge(df_margin), 'left')

  item  sequence  margin
0    a         1     NaN
1    a         2     NaN
2    a         3     3.0
3    b         1     NaN
4    b         2     4.0
5    c         1     NaN
6    c         2     NaN
7    c         3     5.0
```

Breakdown:

```
df_new = df_item.groupby('item')['sequence'].max().reset_index().merge(df_margin)
df_item.merge(df_new, 'left')
```